# referencing an array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Working with the following code:

```
Array0 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
Array1 = ['c', 'd', 'e'];
Array2 = ['x', 'a', 'd'];
...

/*
doStuff() is a recursive function whose argument is an abitrary length array
containing an arbitrary list of array names
e.g., anArr = ['Array1', 'Array0', 'Array1', 'Array2', ...]
*/

function doStuff(anArr) {

    for(i=0; i<anArr.length; i++)   {

      switch(anArr[i])  {
      case('Array0')    :   Array0.myMethod(); break;
      case('Array1')    :   Array1.myMethod(); break;
      case('Array2')    :   Array2.myMethod(); break;
      }

    }
}
```

Is there a way to replace the switch() block with a single statement:

```
<<array referenced by 'someArray'>>.aMethod()   //or
function aFunction (<<array referenced by 'someArray'>>){}
```

Plain Javascript, please - no jquery or other library.
Thanks

Comment: You need to store it in a JavaScript object.

Comment: Change that to an array of arrays.

Answer (score 4):

Use an object in the first place.

```
var foo = {
  Array0 : ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  Array1 : ['c', 'd', 'e'];
  Array2 : ['x', 'a', 'd'];
}
```

Then you can:

```
foo[anArr[i]].myMethod();
```

Comment: won't work for my app, because an array is allowed to be a member of another array: `var foo = {
  A0 : ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  A1 : ['c', 'd', 'e'],
  A2 : ['x', 'a', 'd', A0]` dies.
}

Comment: If you need to reference part of an object from another part of it, then just define all the parts in variables first, and then put them together into the object afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

You can store the actual arrays in the array...

```
Array0 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
Array1 = ['c', 'd', 'e'];
Array2 = ['x', 'a', 'd'];

var anArr = [Array0, Array1, Array2];
for(i=0; i<anArr.length; i++) {
    anArr[i].myMethod();
}
```

Comment: This won't work in my application, because arrays may have arrays whose members are only defined subsequently. - `Array0 =['a', Array1];  Array1 = ['b', 'c'];`, which would throw an undefined variable error  That's not apparent from the code I posted.  Sorry.

Comment: @grymlord — You'd get that problem with your existing code anyway.